# Problem with ZSI

Tags: python, zsi

I biuld web service with ZSI from [example](http://www.pha.com.au/kb/index.php/Python_SOAP_Tutorial_-_Creating_a_WEB_Service_with_ZSI) 
but after sending request I catch next XML

```
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ZSI="http://www.zolera.com/schemas/ZSI/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <SOAP-ENV:Header/>
   <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <SOAP-ENV:Fault>
         <faultcode>SOAP-ENV:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>Processing Failure</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ZSI:FaultDetail>
               <ZSI:string>iteration over non-sequence</ZSI:string>
               <ZSI:trace>build\bdist.win32\egg\ZSI\ServiceContainer.py:108:_Dispatch</ZSI:trace>
            </ZSI:FaultDetail>
         </detail>
      </SOAP-ENV:Fault>
   </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

any ideas to solve it?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

here is the right example 
http://pywebsvcs.sourceforge.net/holger.pdf